# WCF - NetTcp and basicHttp with SSL in single setup possible without IIS7

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf

Is it possible to have both

- NetTcp bound endpoints, and
- basicHttp bound endpoints with SSL

within a single deployment, either using Windows Service or IIS6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a single service host can expose multiple endpoints with different bindings. However, normal IIS restrictions apply to IIS, so IIS 6 doesn't support NetTcp bindings to begin with.

Comment: Understand multiple endpoinds (which we already do), I am interested in the two endpoint types mentioned above in a single service.

Comment: Yes, what jezell said is correct. You can expose a service on multiple endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with IIS 7.0 you *can* use the net.tcp binding with IIS. And *Yes* you can expose multiple bindings (i.e. wsHttpBinding and net.tcp) in a single WCF service installation. The following (2) links should help:

**Multiple Endpoints:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx

**IIS 7 : Support for non-HTTP Protocols:**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/08/iis-7-support-for-non-http-protocols.aspx